# Can I render and debug Objective-C code in VSCode

Tags: objective-c, visual-studio-code

My project comprises a C++ core, iOS and Android wrappers (ObjC / Java) and a Python-wrapping-CMake build-system.

C++ works fine. However an Obj-C header file (with .h extension) marks syntax errors everywhere:

[image]

Does there exist some extension for handling this? I can't find one anywhere.

Comment: Yes, you could use Objective-C, if you have a compiler that knows it. However, you will also need the libraries, `Foundation` for `NSString`, for example. There is an open-source port of Foundation but in general this is not an easy task to do. If this is on a mac machine, it's certainly possible since other IDEs can do it. They use Xcode components to achieve that.

Answer (score 1):

Xcode is a complex combination of different applications like interface builder, instruments, device manager, and many more. These were separate applications at a time, so putting all this together in some other IDE wouldn't be an easy task. However, there are few people trying with tools like [AppCoda](https://www.appcoda.com), but still too far from an actual product.